# Правильная стоимость скрипта

Tags: php, webmoney

Прикручивал одному клиенту WebMoney мерчант, не первый раз, но цены везде разные говорят. Сейчас этот же клиент попросил прикрутить к Я.деньгам, чтобы выполнялся тот же обработчик который я делал для вебмани. Сколько за это можно взять? А то когда первый раз прикручивал к Вебмани, делал это за 10т.р., этому клиенту сделал за копейки, за 2т.р. Толком не пойму, сколько брать) В общем, вопрос: сколько взять за автооплату в ВебМани и Я.Деньгах, с учётом того, что то действие, которое должно выполняться после удачной оплаты, уже реализовано?

Comment: Если для вас это как раз плюнуть, берите 10 тыс. Ну или максимально возможную сумму, не знаю какая там.

Comment: Странные у Вас расценки. IMHO меньше пары килобаксов (хоть бы и за день работы у заказчика) даже разговоры говорить не стоит. 

Иначе Вы совсем клиентов развратите.

Comment: avp, А зачем так не серьёзно отвечать? Почему нельзя сказать, сколько бы Вы взяли? Или Вы относитесь к тем, кто работает за еду и 2т.р. для Вас до смешного большая цена?

Comment: @Asen А почему вы так уверены, что автор плохо справляется с поставленной задачей?

Comment: @Asen, что Вы) Мне просто хочется узнать, как не продешевить и не переборщить, сколько будет стоить прикрутить платёжные системы для автоматического приёма денег. Уверен, доходы у большинства здесь сидящих в разы больше.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что обсуждение цены работы является оффтопиком, а цены перестают быть актуальными слишком быстро.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело не в трудоемкости работы, а в ее нужности/ценности для клиента. Подумайте об этом. В принципе, не играет роли какие у вас трудозатраты. Насколько клиент ценит вашу работу/приладу - настолько он и заплатит. А уж как он вас ценит это вам виднее. В идеале, конечно бы, сделать надо так, чтобы клиент без вас жить не мог (это мечта любого прогера).

Коню понятно, что 10 тыс. это верхняя граница. 2 штуки ИМХО маловато (так недолго и клиента развратить) я бы взял 6-7 штук. Скидка 30% - клиенту приятно и вам неплохо. Можете при случае клиенту сказать что в следующий раз будет еще дышевле.

P.S. И штуку мне за консультацию :)

Comment: Неужели, нормальный ответ)) Таких ответов я и ждал)) Спасибо. Жду ещё мнения других)

Comment: @mctrane где моя штука за консультацию?! :)

Answer (score 3):

А я бы о другом задумался... В первый раз вы "привязали" клиента своей вкусной ценой и он вернулся. Не рвите сцепление, иначе он так же легко от вас уйдет.

У меня когда-то, в начале моей карьеры, похожее было. Казалось, что продешевил, но зато мой первый клиент привел ко мне более десятка других, которым я уже ставил нормальные рассценки.

Comment: Хм, я, руководствуясь схожими идеями, пару раз делал вещи за бесценок. *В итоге ни денег, ни новых клиентов :)*

Comment: Ну, так к любой "афёре" надо с умом подходить ))) В крайности тоже впадать не надо.

Comment: `@Котик_хочет_кушать` "я вас так понимаю" ©

Comment: "Вкусной ценой" клиентов привязали дурачки, которые практические за любую задачу берут копейки. Я клиенту сначала сказал 5к, после чего он сказал, что больше 2-х не даст, т.к. ему на фрилансе бы сделали вообще 1 т.р. или ещё лучше за отзыв)) Для меня эта тема знакома и интересна, я не стал отказываться, ибо сам не знаю, может 5т.р. - это действительно очень большая цена для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Правильная стоимость скрипта - ноль. Когда он продан - см. с своём кошельке.

Answer (score -1):

Если ты уже делал этому клиенту за некую сумму такую же работу, то увеличение стоимости должно бы покзаться подозрительным. Занижать стоимость в данном случае тоже как-то сомнительно. Мне кажется, имеет смысл назвать ту же цену.